# Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file://android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: cordova

I'm building a cordova application, works fine with older version of android, when trying with an android 9 device this error occurred.

My client hase 7 android device with different android releases, I've created this app working with an android 7 device and works perfectly fine, when I installed the app on the new android 9 device this error occurres. I've tryed all the possible solutions found online:

- changing the timeout in the config.xml

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

- changing the timeout in the MainActivity.java

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
```

- redirecting from "index.html" to "main.html";
- uninstalling and reinstalling android platform;
- using the cordova crosswalk plugin;
- downgrading the cordova version;
- upgrading the cordova version.

I'm thinking of downgrading the android version on all the android 9 devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. This error occurres even when for some reason Android uses as default WebView Chrome and avoid the Android default WebView, to solve this issue you can select the default WebView from the Deveoper options, in case the selection is locked you have to uninstall chrome or deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command for build .apk

```
cordova build android --prod
```